# React Native - How do I specify state in tests?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing

I am currently working on a React Native component that uses local state to control some UI elements, ie, some elements are only rendered if some values in state are set to `true`. These values change depending on clicks within the component.

Is there a way for me to specify initial state when testing using react's `TestRenderer`? If not, how could I go around to testing this? I'd like to be able to render the component for certain states and test over it. Any helpful input is very much appreciated.

I can provide more detail if necessary.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Adding an example illustrating my code. This is not my component code but it illustrates its behavior:

```
interface IMyComponentProps {
    ...
}

interface IMyComponentState {
    showForm: boolean;
}

export class MyComponent extends React.Component<IMyComponentProps, IMyComponentState> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        // showForm is initially false
        this.state = {
            showForm: false,
        };
    }

    public render() {
        // if showForm is true then render my form component
        if (this.state.showForm) {
            return <FormComponent />;
        } else {
            // otherwise render button that changes the state to showForm: true
            // and causes a re-render
            return <Button onClick={this.buttonClickFn} />;
        }
    }

    private buttonClickFn = () => this.setState({...this.state, showForm: true});
}
```

Comment: Can you add your component code?

Comment: @gran33 I added some example component code illustrating what I mean. If you need any more details please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state can be directly set for testing purposes:

```
componentInstance.state.showForm = true;
componentInstance.forceUpdate();
```

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what I needed. +1